# Cron Jobs vs Task Scheduler table for scheduled emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-dynamodb, scheduled-tasks, backend

Preamble: I have a web app, the backend is based on the serverless architecture. It's basically an amplify app hosted on AWS with a dynamoDB database. I've learnt is possible to create a task scheduling system of sorts [more here](https://medium.com/monstar-lab-bangladesh-engineering/how-i-solved-dynamic-task-scheduling-using-aws-dynamodb-ttl-stream-and-lambda-c0da5ebd6597). A quick summary of the article is "Its possible to create a task scheduling table taking advantage of TTL and dynamoDB streams to execute lambda function at specific times. The TTL specifies a set time for an record to be deleted, we can capture this delete event in a dynamoDB stream and run some tasks based on information from the stream"

Problem:
The goal is to send a series of emails to users who sign up for our service. Each user that signs up gets a series of "Getting Started" emails. The first of the emails is sent 24 hours after a user signs up, the second 3 days later and the third exactly 7 days after sign up.

I see how a cron job would be suitable here, but it just seems a bit inefficient to me. I would basically have to search the users table for users whose sign up time falls between a specific 24 hour period and send the email to the users whereas with a Task scheduler table I could add a task to the table ( something like `send first email to user300` with a TTL of when I want it to be sent ) and listen for delete events to run the task. No need to run a cron job daily, just a function that handles each task as it comes.

I think this is more like a performance vs storage problem. Having a task scheduler table would take up space, if we add all the emails to be sent to a user as tasks on the table (each email to be sent to a specific user is it's own task) each time a user signs up then I see the task scheduler table growing 3n records for every n user signed up. But this may not really be a problem as tasks are deleted after they are run. I do not know the performance cost of using a cron job for this particular task hence I'm here. I also may be wrong and the cost of running and updating this task scheduler table may be more than that of the cron job.

I initially thought of setting up a dummy user table and running both the cron and the task scheduler and documenting cost of running both, but you can imagine how much time and effort that would take.

So I guess my question is which is a more efficient solution in terms of performance and cost?

Answer (score 3):

There is no perfect solution here. Keep in mind that Dynamodb TTL takes up to 48h to invoke, so it's probably unacceptable. CRON Jobs with Lambda are cheap, and it's easy to set. You coul also use SQS and populate it with daily CRON. Yan Cui wrote great article about this problem https://theburningmonk.com/2019/03/dynamodb-ttl-as-an-ad-hoc-scheduling-mechanism/

Comment: Hi. Its 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

This may not exactly be an answer. Based on the medium article you linked the guy had a plausible reason why the TTL and dynamoDB streams would be better than a cron job which you reiterated. Setting up a cron job is easier and cheaper (free) and I doubt the performance will be that much worse unless the database is huge. I don't have any experience doing something like this so I wouldn't know how large the database would have to be for it to make sense to switch over. Alternatively, you can have as many cron jobs as you want so I don't see how you couldn't just set up a user specific cron job whenever someone signs up.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a CloudWatch Event to fire a Lambda function on a regular schedule. The Lambda function can search a database for an applicable result set and perform other actions - send an email, a text message, etc.

Here is an AWS tutorial that covers a very similar use case with step by step instructions. This tutorial is implemented by using the AWS Java API (but you can implement it using other supported programming languages).

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_scheduled_events

From a Cost perspective - Lambda allows 1M free requests per month. Details are here - https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/